# Bulk Load Multiple Worksheets of an Excel Workbook parallelly into SQL DB using Azure Data Factory V2

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

Is there a way to Bulk Load worksheets into SQL tables using ADF V2 ?

I was able to load 5 Sheets of data by making 10 Data sets (Excel and SQL Tables) using 2 linked Service (Blob & SQL DB). The performance wasn't good even when all of the data activities were executed in parallel.

If I add more sheets to load, then performance degrades significantly. I assume it's because the same excel workbook is consumed and it takes time to open and read considering it's size (50 MB) and becomes a bottleneck.

SSIS could do it only sequentially using the Foreach loop (depends how dynamically the destination table was set)

There must be a better way to load the data rather than creating N*2 number of Data sets (Worksheet Source & Resp SQL Table).

-Thanks

Comment: You can click "edit" in the dataset "sheets" property and parameterize that property. Then you can use a pipeline "foreach" to loop through sheet names.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @Mark has posted - "You can click "edit" in the dataset "sheets" property and parameterize that property. Then you can use a pipeline "foreach" to loop through sheet names"

Answer (score 1):

You could do this in two steps:

- First export the excel spreadsheets to csv files, you could combined these to a single file.
- Then use Bulk Insert to load the data into the database

See: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/bulk-insert-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15

Comment: I don't think it can be done via ADF as there isn't an activity to execute an SQL Command autonomously. Moreover there is an added overhead to convert Excel into CSV(s) first.

Comment: Most of the time is consumed by writing to the transaction log, bulk insert avoids this. Is using ADF a requirement?

Comment: The SQL server ID(s) won't be having access of Storage Containers. Hence ADF.

Comment: You could use an external process that has access to both the SQL server and the Storage Containers